# AngularJs Intranet Windows Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I'm working on angular app for intranet application. I hosted angular and WebApi in IIS as separate application. I need to validate the current windows logged-in user against Active-Directory group. So when user loads the angular page, it should automatically send in the logged-in userId. I tried with $windows service, but it does not have the user information.

Any approach which I could use here.

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to get the windows logged-in user ? I'm in the same boat, could you share your solution?

Comment: Not yet, was busy with my other stuffs. I am still analyzing...

Comment: FYI: https://gist.github.com/danbergman/e67e5cbe3e9943ecbb03